# Pandas module not found, Windows server 2012

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, anaconda

All,

I'm running on a Windows 2012 server with Anaconda 2.3.0 64b (2.7) installed and am trying to also have Python 3.6 available. I've installed 3.6 but can't get it to load pandas. I saw another thread that seemed to tie the issue to conda.

I removed and installed pandas again and reset my path to not look at the Anaconda directory but I'm still getting the error.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
PS C:\Users\yearickp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36> .\python -m pip list
Package         Version
--------------- -------
numpy           1.14.3
pandas          0.23.0
pip             10.0.1
pyodbc          4.0.23
python-dateutil 2.7.3
pytz            2018.4
setuptools      39.1.0
six             1.11.0
SQLAlchemy      1.2.7
PS C:\Users\yearickp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36> .\python
Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\yearickp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 42, in <mod
ule>
    from pandas.core.api import *
  File "C:\Users\yearickp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 10, in <mod
ule>
    from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import Grouper
  File "C:\Users\yearickp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\__init__.py", lin
e 2, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import (
  File "C:\Users\yearickp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line
 49, in <module>
    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
  File "C:\Users\yearickp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 74, in <m
odule>
    from pandas.core.series import Series
  File "C:\Users\yearickp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 3978, in
 <module>
    Series._add_series_or_dataframe_operations()
  File "C:\Users\yearickp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 8891, i
n _add_series_or_dataframe_operations
    from pandas.core import window as rwindow
  File "C:\Users\yearickp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window.py", line 36, in <
module>
    import pandas._libs.window as _window
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with v0.23. Uninstall pandas `pip uninstall pandas` and install v0.22 instead `pip install pandas==0.22` (except you really have to use v0.23).

Comment: Thank you letroot, that worked and no, I do not specifically need v0.23.